# Data is not synced to View in Lightning componet

Tags: lightning-aura-components

**Component Code**

```
<div class="slds-p-horizontal--medium slds-p-vertical--xx-small slds-text-body--regular slds-text-align--left">
    <div class="slds-page-header" >
        <div class="slds-grid">
            <div class="slds-media__body" style="font-weight: bold">   
                <p class="slds-text-title"><span  >
                    <lightning:icon iconName="standard:related_list" variant="bare"  size="small"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;Visits  <button style="margin-left:30px;" class="slds-button slds-button--brand">New</button></span>
                </p> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-scrollable--y" style="height:240px;">
        <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-max-medium-table--stacked-horizontal">
            <thead>
                <tr class="slds-text-title--caps">
                    <th class="slds-cell-shrink" scope="col">
                        Action
                    </th>
                    <th class="slds-is-sortable" scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Visit Date">Visit Date

                        </div>
                    </th>
                    <th class="slds-is-sortable" scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Visit Type">Visit Type

                        </div>
                    </th>
                    <th class="slds-is-sortable" scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Visit Reason">Visit Reason

                        </div>
                    </th>
                    <th class="slds-is-sortable" scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Discharge Date">Discharge Date

                        </div>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.patientDetails}" var="patientDetail" indexVar="index" >
                    <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
                        <td class="slds-cell-shrink" data-label="Action">
                            <aura:if isTrue="{!patientDetail.IsEdit}">
                                <a class="slds-button" data-index="{!index}" onclick="{! c.rowEditCancel }">Cancel</a> |<a  class="slds-button" data-index="{!index}" onclick="{! c.rowUpdate}">Update</a>                                    
                                <aura:set attribute="else">
                                    <a class="slds-button" data-index="{!index}" onclick="{! c.rowEdit }">Edit</a>
                                </aura:set>
                            </aura:if>  
                        </td> 
                        <td data-label="visit Date"> 
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="visit Date">
                                <aura:if isTrue="{!patientDetail.IsEdit}">
                                    <ui:inputDate class="field"  aura:id="txtVisitDate"  value="{!patientDetail.patient.Visit_Date__c}" displayDatePicker="true" />
                                    <aura:set attribute="else">
                                        {!patientDetail.patient.Visit_Date__c}
                                    </aura:set>
                                </aura:if> 
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-label="visit Type">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="visit Type">
                                <aura:if isTrue="{!patientDetail.IsEdit}">
                                    <ui:inputSelect aura:id="ddlCategory"  value="{!patientDetail.patient.Category__c}" >
                                        <ui:inputSelectOption text="Hospitalization" />
                                        <ui:inputSelectOption text="ER Visit" />
                                        <ui:inputSelectOption text="Office Visit" />
                                    </ui:inputSelect>
                                    <aura:set attribute="else">
                                        <ui:outputText value="{!patientDetail.patient.Category__c}" />
                                    </aura:set>
                                </aura:if> 
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-label="Visit Reasion">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Visit Reasion">
                                <aura:if isTrue="{!patientDetail.IsEdit}">
                                    <ui:inputTextArea aura:id="txtReasion"  value="{!patientDetail.patient.Visit_Reason__c}" />
                                    <aura:set attribute="else">
                                        <ui:outputText value="{!patientDetail.patient.Visit_Reason__c}"/>
                                    </aura:set>
                                </aura:if> 
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-label="Discharge Date">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Discharge Date">
                                <aura:if isTrue="{!patientDetail.IsEdit}">
                                    <ui:inputDate class="field" aura:id="txtDischargeDate"   value="{!patientDetail.patient.Discharge_Date__c}" displayDatePicker="true" />
                                    <aura:set attribute="else">
                                        {!patientDetail.patient.Discharge_Date__c}
                                    </aura:set>
                                </aura:if> 
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr> 
                </aura:iteration>     
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

`

**Javascript Controller Code**

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {

        helper.getPatientVisits(component);
    },
    rowEdit:function(cmp, event,helper){

        var target = event.target;
        var rowIndex = target.getAttribute("data-index");
        var records =  cmp.get("v.patientDetails");

        for( var i =0;i<records.length;i++){
          records[i].IsEdit = false;
        }
        records[rowIndex].IsEdit = true;
        cmp.set("v.patientDetails",records);
    }, 
    rowEditCancel:function(cmp, event,helper){

        var target = event.target;
        var rowIndex = target.getAttribute("data-index");
        var records =  cmp.get("v.patientDetails");
        records[rowIndex].IsEdit = false;
        cmp.set("v.patientDetails",records);
    },
    rowUpdate:function(cmp, event,helper){

        var target = event.target;
        var rowIndex = target.getAttribute("data-index");
        var records =  cmp.get("v.patientDetails");
        records[rowIndex].IsEdit = false;



        cmp.set("v.patientDetails",records);
    },
})
```

**Apex Controller**

```
public with sharing class PatientListingController {

 @AuraEnabled
    public static List<PatientDetail> getPatientVisits(string patientId){ 

        List<PatientDetail> lstPatientDetails = new List<PatientDetail> ();

       for(Patient_Detail__c record : [SELECT ID .......... ]){
             lstPatientDetails.add(new PatientDetail(record));                
          }
        return lstPatientDetails; 
    } 


public class PatientDetail{
      @AuraEnabled  
    public Boolean IsEdit{get;set;}
      @AuraEnabled
    public Patient_Detail__c patient{get;set;}

    public PatientDetail(Patient_Detail__c patient){
        this.patient = patient;
        IsEdit = false;
    }

    } 
}
```

Comment: Provide more details on what you need.Data Not synced are you saying the data entered in UI doesnt show up in UI?

Comment: Whenever we enter data in input text in inline edit and clicking on update button it not shows in view mode...